# Converting strings to floats in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list of lists which contain strings of numbers and words 
I want to convert only those strings which are numbers to floats

```
aList= [ ["hi", "1.33"], ["bye", " 1.555"] ]
```

Comment: Ok.  What have you `try`ed? (*hint*)

Answer (score 4):

First, you need a function that does the "convert a string to float if possible, otherwise leave it as a string":

```
def floatify(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

Now, you can just call that on each value, either generating a new list, or modifying the old one in place.

Since you have a nested list, this means a nested iteration. You might want to start by doing it explicitly in two steps:

```
def floatify_list(lst):
    return [floatify(s) for s in lst]

def floatify_list_of_lists(nested_list):
    return [floatify_list(lst) for lst in nested_list]
```

You can of course combine it into one function just by making `floatify_list` a local function:

```
def floatify_list_of_lists(nested_list):
    def floatify_list(lst):
        return [floatify(s) for s in lst]
    return [floatify_list(lst) for lst in nested_list]
```

You could also do it by substituting the inner expression in place of the function call. If you can't figure out how to do that yourself, I would recommend not doing it, because you're unlikely to understand it (complex nested list comprehensions are hard enough for experts to understand), but if you must:

```
def floatify_list_of_lists(nested_list):
    return [[floatify(s) for s in lst] for lst in nested_list]
```

Or, if you prefer your Python to look like badly-disguised Haskell:

```
def floatify_list_of_lists(nested_list):
    return map(partial(map, floatify), nested_list)
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish there were a ternary-like exception handling:  `try float(s) except (ValueError,TypeError) s` sort of thing ...

Comment: @mgilson: You can write that pretty easily as a function. See http://ideone.com/trX7EX for the idea.v (You can `partial` up `tryify(float)` to make the example in this case even simpler.)

Comment: Sure.  I could do the same thing with conditional expressions:  `def ifify(x,condition,y): if condition: return x;return y` :) -- Your function is kinda neat though.  I do like it.

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, but I think in this case, the use case isn't common enough, and the function version isn't ugly enough, that new syntax would be warranted. (Keep in mind that Guido barely found it warranted enough in the conditional expression case, so his tolerance is even lower than mine.) I _do_ think this function would be useful in the stdlib, or at least a recipe in the docs, but that idea was shot down on python-ideas years ago (just like `iter_with` more recently). So, now I just write it myself in any project where I find myself needing it often, and end up giving it a different name…

Comment: How would I write this in one step as one function

Comment: @abarnert HOW CAN I MAKE THIS ONE FUNCTION??

Comment: @BAI: There is no need to shout in all caps. I still can't hear you when I'm across the office from my computer.